# usage user details inside Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net Core 3.1 API hosted in Azure App Service and this API uses the Azure AD to authenticate the users. I have requirement to show the list of users that have accessed this API.

app insights always show **Zero** users.

Things I have tried

1. Enabled the AppInsigts of web app
2. Enabled the telemetry in StartUp.cs

`services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options => Configuration.Bind("ApplicationInsights", options))`

3. Created the telemetry class to pass the User context

   ```
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var ctx = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        if (ctx != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx.User.Identity.Name) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.User.Id) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Session.Id)))
            {
                telemetry.Context.User.Id = ctx.User.Identity.Name;
                telemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = ctx.User.Identity.Name;
                telemetry.Context.Session.Id = ctx.User.Identity.Name;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Still I don't see any user in Azure portal

Comment: where are you registering the `itelemetry initializer`(I see you used it in step 3)?

Comment: inside the startup.cs class